# How to add stuff by index

Tags: python-polars

Seems like Polars is not a fan of Pandas indexes.

There are some things that you can do with indexes that I don't know how to do in Polars.

For example say I have `test = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b'],'b':[3,4]})` and `test1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b'],'b':[4,5]})`, in Pandas I can add the two (with a being the index column).

In Polars when I try to add the two, I get string concatenation behavior for the a column, which I don't want. Is there a way to do what I want here?

Comment: Can you edit your question with an example of what you want to achieve? How do you do it in pandas and what is the result you  expected?

Comment: Let's say we have two dataframe df1, d2, each with a categorical column, b and another float column c. We can do df1.groupby("b").agg({"c":"sum"}) + df2.groupby("b").agg({"c":"sum"}) in pandas. The addition will do index match on the values of "b", which is now the index after the groupby.

Comment: What you need is a join.

Comment: That;s what I figured I need to do in Polars. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you make that an answer I can accept it

Comment: I don't fully understand you question. Can you edit it with a minimal example? So create a DataFrame with some data and the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments by ritchie46 you can use a join like this:

```py
# pandas version with index and implicit join on add
import pandas as pd
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b'],'b':[3,4]}).set_index('a')
test2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b'],'b':[4,5]}).set_index('a')
result = test1 + test2
print(result)

┌─────┬─────┐  
│ a   ┆ b   │  
╞═════╪═════╡  
│ a   ┆ 7   │  
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤  
│ b   ┆ 9   │  
└─────┴─────┘
```

```py
# polars version with explicit join
import polars as pl
test1 = pl.DataFrame({'a':['a','b'],'b':[3,4]})
test2 = pl.DataFrame({'a':['a','b'],'b':[4,5]})
result = test1.join(test2, on='a').select(['a', pl.col('b')+pl.col('b_right')])
print(result)

┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ a   ┆ 7   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┘
```